# Do relics persist over multiple campaigns?

Tags: space-hulk-deathwing

After learning that relics existed as a collectible in the campaign missions I set about getting all of them but, I only started looking after the first two missions and, as such, missed a few.

Now I've completed the campaign and would like to gather the rest but the game lacks a mission select and so I must start a new campaign in order to get all of the relics (along with the achievement).

In order to get the achievement and/or complete the relic screen, can I just grab the ones I missed or do I have to gather every single one again?